# Multiple substitution with SymPy in Julia

Tags: python, julia, sympy

I am using **SymPy** in **Julia**. I have the following code:

```
using SymPy

# Define variables and function

alpha_m, alpha_r, cm, cr phi = Sym("alpha_m", "alpha_r", "cm", "cr", "phi");

X = 1+(alpha_r/alpha_m)^(1/(1-phi))*(cr/cm)^(phi/(1-phi));
```

Now, I want to replace several expressions by other variables:

```
# New definitions

m, r = Sym("m","r");
```

I try three methods, but only the last one works, which is writing the sub for each individual redefinition:

```
# Multiple replacement

toin = (alpha_m, alpha_r);
toout = (m/(m+r),r/(m+r));

X = subs(X,zip(toin,toout)) # NOT WORKING

X = subs(X,[alpha_m,m/(m+r),alpha_r,r/(m+r)]); # NOT WORKING

X = subs(X,alpha_m,m/(m+r))
X = subs(X,alpha_r,r/(m+r)) # WORKING
```

Is there any way to do multiple substitutions at once, like I try in the first two methods?

Comment: You can use Unicode, ie. `X = 1 + (αᵣ / αₐ)^(1 / (1 - ϕ))*(cr / cm)^(ϕ / (1 - ϕ))` http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/?highlight=completion#tab-completion

Comment: In order to type at the Julia **REPL** (and other environments) the letter *phi*, start typing `\ph` press `TAB` to autocomplete to `\phi`, press `TAB` again to replace it for: `ϕ`, the other ones can be composed like this: `\alpha<TAB>\_r<TAB>` for `αᵣ` http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/?highlight=completion#tab-completion

Comment: What does this relate to my question?

Comment: It's not, but it's related to the style which is why it's just a comment not an answer. Others might find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first construct with splatting:

`X = subs(X,zip(toin,toout)...)`